# Can gradle do substitutions as it copies resources?

Tags: groovy, gradle

For a group of developers, all the differences are stored in a normal property file:

```
token1=some value
token2=9000
etc.
```

The 'tokens' are used in a series of XML files that reside in the normal src/main/resources directory.  When Gradle copies these files into the build directory (and I don't know for sure what task that is), is there any opportunity to execute custom code?   Specifically, I would like to have the token values from the property file substituted into the copy.  Thus, the original copy remains untouched, but the version in the runtime has the desired values for the given developer.

Finally, I know this can done brute force with two or three steps that change the file after it is copied.  I really want to know if there is an elegant way to do this in a single step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After compilation, Gradle calls `processResources` task that copies the resources into the build directory. While copying resources, [`processResources`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/language/jvm/tasks/ProcessResources.html) can be configured to do the filtering (or possibly execute custom code by adding a `doLast`):

```
processResources {
    filter org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
      ...
    ]
}
```

These two links can provide more help:

- http://java.dzone.com/articles/resource-filtering-gradle
- http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2010/11/gradle-goodness-add-filtering-to.html